# JQuery drop down for mobile not working the way it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay this is the deal, I'm a student working on my final website for class and we need to have some javascript/jquery in our site. I didn't want to get to crazy so I just settled for a drop down menu for mobile devices. My only problem is if I link a page in my tutorials button of my navigation it automatically goes to that page ans doesn't allow me to tap tutorials again. I hope that makes sense, please let me know if it doesn't. My navigation mark up is...

```
<nav role="navigation" aria-label="Main menu">

<ul role="menubar">
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="index.html" class="mainmenu">Home</a></li>
<li class="mainmenu" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup=true tabindex="0"><a href="production.html" class="mainmenu">Tutorials</a>

<ul class="submenu" role="menu" aria-hidden=true>

<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="pre-pro.html">Pre-Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="production.html">Production</a></li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="-1"><a href="post.html">Post</a></li>

</ul>
</li>
<li role="menuitem" tabindex="0"><a href="films.html" class="mainmenu">Films</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

The JQuery Plugin I found is the following...

```
;(function( $, window, document, undefined )
{
    $.fn.doubleTapToGo = function( params )
    {
        if( !( 'ontouchstart' in window ) &&
            !navigator.msMaxTouchPoints &&
            !navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match( /windows phone os 7/i ) ) return false;

        this.each( function()
        {
            var curItem = false;

            $( this ).on( 'click', function( e )
            {
                var item = $( this );
                if( item[ 0 ] != curItem[ 0 ] )
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    curItem = item;
                }
            });

            $( document ).on( 'click touchstart MSPointerDown', function( e )
            {
                var resetItem = true,
                    parents   = $( e.target ).parents();

                for( var i = 0; i < parents.length; i++ )
                    if( parents[ i ] == curItem[ 0 ] )
                        resetItem = false;

                if( resetItem )
                    curItem = false;
            });
        });
        return this;
    };
})( jQuery, window, document );
```

and this is where I had found the plugin http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly in case you want something to reference. Thank you for any help in advance. Cheers!

Comment: That plugin code doesn't seem to be connected to your HTML in any useful way.

Comment: Its connected like so...<link rel="script" href="scripts/doubletaptogo.js">

Comment: That's how it's loaded. What tells the plugin which element(s) to act on? Where is it initialized?

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't know. What I do know is that the plugin works to almost perfectly. My only problem is when I put a page name in my 'a' of tutorials, i can't just touch tutorials and then once more to actually go to that page.

Answer (score 0):

From the source of the example page:

```
<script>
$( function()
{
    $( '#nav li:has(ul)' ).doubleTapToGo();
});
</script>
```